# Relative path using "./"

Tags: php, path

Im working with some code that uses "./" to describe a path to the stylesheet in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/style.css">
```

I am familiar with "../" - *go up one level and follow path from there*

and "/" - *follow path from root directory*

It seems "./" is a relative path but why use it at all? Why not just write the path as public/css/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ means relative to the current directory.

You are correct, the two ways of writing the path are exactly the same and both will work fine.

Using ./ may help in the case that a script generates the path.

Comment: a script generating a path is exactly what is happening here. makes sense now, thank you!